# Data modelling for ecommerce website using Amplify + GraphQL + DynamoDB

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I'm using Amplify from AWS to build a small ecommerce project using React as frontend.

I'd like to know how I should write the "Product" and "Order" types in the schema in order to be able to write productId's to a product array in the Order table when users complete a purchase.

My schema.graphql file:

```
type Product @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  price: Int!
  category: String!
  images: [String]!
}

type Order @model {
  id: ID!
  products: [Product] @connection
}
```

My question is about the last line, do I need to define that [Product] connection there or I can use [String] to store product id's in a simple string array?

Comment: If you are looking to make a one-to-many connection between Order and Products, then your schema is correct

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1:** In dynamoDB, you only need to define the data type of your partition key and sort key, and these can be string, number etc. For all the other attributes, you don't need to define anything.

**Point 2:** The dynamoDB designers prefer using a single table per application, unless it's impossible to manage data without multiple tables. Keeping this in mind, your table can be something like this.

[image]

**Please observe:** Only **Id** aka partition key and **Sk** aka sort key column is fixed here, all other columns can be anything per item. This is the beauty of DynamoDB. Refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes) document for dynamoDB supported data types.

Comment: I agree that having only one table is ideal and the recommended way to use DynamoDB. However in many examples from Amplify (AWS) documentation, they use the multiple-table approach: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/overview